# Proper PDF metadata key to enable right-to-left viewing in "Facing" view mode in PDF readers

Tags: pdf, metadata, arabic

I was wondering whether anyone knew the proper PDF metadata key (and value) in order to signify to PDF readers that the PDF in facing mode should be displayed from right-to-left (RTL) and not left-to-right. I use many Arabic PDFs (mainly scanned, not typed) and apparently no one encodes them properly (or whatever software they are using does not support the feature). I would like to edit the metadata so I can view pages in facing mode properly.

(I assume somebody who creates PDFs of Japanese manga, as well as Hebrew etc. documents would know this. I was unable to find a real PDF specification regarding this.)

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-I-page-order-left-page-view-q2723.aspx) will help.

Comment: @Karan Thanks a lot! From that link this method did work: "File menu : Properties : Advanced : Reading options : Binding : Right Edge

This will revert page order."

I tried it on a friend's copy of Acrobat (don't have one myself). I'm looking into preferably free methods though. If I could find a metadata editor (CLI or GUI) that allows me to edit the Root object it would be perfect. See [link](http://forums.fofou.org/sumatrapdf/topic?id=3183525) for the info the dev of Sumatra PDF provided. So far I did find BeCyPDFMetaEdit (GUI) which does not seem to allow that, and ditto with pdftk (CLI).

Comment: There are lots more PDF metadata editors available, such as [this](http://www.hexonic-software.com/index.php/hexonic-pdf-metadata-editor), [this](http://www.evermap.com/autometadata.asp), [this](http://code.google.com/p/pdf-meta/) and so on. I'm sure at least one of them will allow you to specify RTL order.

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe's [PDF Reference (3rd edition)](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf#8.1%20%20Viewer%20Preferences), setting the `Direction` key under `ViewerPreferences` to `R2L` will set a right-to-left reading order.

Answer (score 0):

As Omer linked it is very simple to tell ACROBAT to use R2L

For Hebrew it could look something like this.

```
2 0 obj
<</Lang(he-IL)/Metadata 3 0 R/Pages 4 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences<</Direction/R2L>>>>
endobj
```

HOWEVER as it shows it is like many PDF features a user "ViewerPreference" so needs to be switched on in a Reader, and some do not have file scripts controlling viewer application switching for securities sake.

Thus very easy to edit a PDF to include it but will not ensure your reader respects it, Acrobat Reader Viewer Preferences will need you to accept PDFs can change your views by itself.

So how its done in other readers (so not browsers) is they will have a user controlled Manga Mode like this currently set to "Book Mode" (separate cover first) and similar for "Facing Mode".

[image]

For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76775303/10802527

So to make the changes you need a program that if the entry is present could switch `Type/Catalog` say from `/ViewerPreferences<</Direction/L2R>>` to `/ViewerPreferences<</Direction/R2L>>` Say

```
cpdf in.pdf -replace-dict-entry /ViewerPreferences -replace-dict-entry-value '{"/Direction": {"N": "/R2L"}}' -o out.pdf
```

**One big problem** is most files do not have `/ViewerPreferences<</Direction/L2R>>` they simply rely on the user setting their own secure choices.

And even if you were to add it in, many readers would not have the ability to swap bindings.